# open an rtmp link with rtmpdumb

Tags: vlc-media-player, rtmp

I am trying to open the following rtmp link :

```
rtmp://$OPT:rtmp-raw=rtmp://178.18.31.60:443/liverepeater playpath=195092 swfUrl=http://bernardotv.club/player6.swf live=1 pageUrl=http://biggestplayer.me/streamcr.php?id=195092&width=620&height=490 token=deadsoon%%7
```

To do this, I use rtmpdumb with the following command line :

```
rtmpdump -v -r "rtmp://$OPT:rtmp-raw=rtmp://178.18.31.60:443/liverepeater playpath=195092 swfUrl=http://bernardotv.club/player6.swf live=1 pageUrl=http://biggestplayer.me/streamcr.php?id=195092&width=620&height=490 token=deadsoon%%7" -o - | "C:\Program Files (x86)\VideoLAN\VLC\vlc.exe" -
```

But I am getting the following error :

```
RTMPDump v2.4
(c) 2010 Andrej Stepanchuk, Howard Chu, The Flvstreamer Team; license: GPL
Connecting ...
ERROR: Problem accessing the DNS. (addr: $OPT)
```